# Is the notion of measurable cardinal definable from the perspective of set-theoretical potentialism?

Tags: set-theory, mathematical-philosophy

Consider the definition of measurable cardinal (this definition was found in Neil Barton's paper, "Large cardinals and the iterative conception of set"):

> Definition 8.  A cardinal $\kappa$ is measurable iff it is the critical point of a non-trivial elementary embedding $j$:  $V$ $\rightarrow$ $M$, for some transitive inner model $\mathfrak M$ = ($M$, $\in$ ).

Given my limited understanding of set-theoretic potentialism, the above definition seems to me to rest on actualist assumptions (in particular, the assumption that $V$ actually exists).

This interpretation is born out of my understanding of current writings of set-theoretic potentialists, in particular, the slide presentation of Joel David Hamkins titled "Potentialism and implicit actualism in the foundations of mathematics" (his Jowett Society lecture, Oxford, February 2019).  Consider the following, from his slide presentation:

> A potentialist system $\mathcal W$ is *convergent*, with limit $M$, if
>
> Every world in $\mathcal W$ is a substructure of $M$.
>
> Every world in $\mathcal W$ can be extended so as to accomodate any desired individual of $M$.

The archetypal limit structure would (at least to actualists) at first glance  seem to be $V$.  However, Prof. Hamkins in another slide, states the following:

> Potentialist translation
>
> For every $\psi$ in $\mathcal L$, form the potentialist translation $\psi^{\lozenge}$ by
>
> replace $\exists$$x$ by $\lozenge$$\exists$$x$       replace $\forall$$x$ by $\Box$$\forall$$x$.
>
> Theorem.  If a potentialist system $\mathcal W$ has has limit $M$ then
>
> $M$ $\vDash$ $\psi$($a$)  $\Longleftrightarrow$ $W$ $\vDash_{\mathcal W}$ $\psi^{\lozenge}$($a$),
>
> for any world $W$ $\in$ $\mathcal W$ in which the individual $a$ exists.
>
> Thus, actual truth in the limit structure amounts to potentialist truthe in the approximating structures.  So the potentialist can in fact refer to th actual truth.
>
> Proved by simple induction on formulas.

Finally, he writes the following:

> The potentialist translation shows that in convergent potentialism, the potentialist can nevertheless accurately refer to truth in the limit structure, which is not part of the potentialist ontology.
>
> Convergent potentialism is thus a form of *implicit actualism*.
>
> Although the actual limit structure does not exist, nevertheless one has a full account of the objects and truths of it in the potentialist language.  It is as though the actual limit structure exists in all the ways that matter.

But is this sufficient enough to derive the notion of measurable cardinal as stated above?

Comment: I honestly don't understand what this is asking. The text you've cited describes a way to translate actualist accounts into potentialist accounts; what does that have to do with a measurable cardinal specifically? Are you asking whether a particular actualist argument for measurables can be translated into a potentialist argument for measurables? If so, what argument do you have in mind?

Comment: I agree that the question is not particularly clear, but one way of making sense of it would be to ask whether one necessarily needs to talk about all of $V$ in order to define measurability, or do bounded pieces of the universe suffice (I suppose "bounded" can be interpreted in different ways, depending on the kind of potentialism one is interested in). If you allow pieces of the from $V_\alpha$, then the answer is yes, as the measurability of $\kappa$ is witnessed by objects somewhere in the neighbourhood of $V_{\kappa+3}$ (either the measure, or just an embedding defined on $V_{\kappa+1}$).

Comment: If you restrict your pieces of the universe to have size at most $\kappa$, then I suspect you won't be able to express measurability, but will get stuck somewhere in the region of a Ramsey cardinal.

Comment: What does this have to do with math philosophy? philosophy can be a motivation for  setting up axioms, but the interest of working with axioms is that one gets rid of philosophical speculations.

Comment: @MihaHabič:  You have essentially understood the point I was trying to make with my question.  Given that $V$ is a limit structure for a convergent potentialist system $\mathcal W$, does the potentialist translation for $V$ (according to the theorem Prof. Hamkins  states in his slide presentation which I quoted) and the fact that $V$ as the limit structure does not exist cause problems (so to speak) for defining measurability in terms of non-trivial elementary embeddings from $V$  to transitive inner models of $V$ (which would be the elements of $\mathcal W$)?  Hope the waters are not further

Comment: (cont.) muddied....

Comment: @YCor:  Actually, one does not get rid of philosophical speculations when working with axioms (as the existence of the set-theoretic muliverse shows), rather, they allow one to study philosophical speculations more precisely.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin— Far predating Hamkins’ notion of potentialism, there have been concerns about the first-order expressibility of large cardinal axioms. Measurable cardinals were first characterized in combinatorial terms, motivated by questions from the early days of analysis.  Then came the useful elementary embedding characterization.  A general stance is that large cardinals should have a first-order formulation, which I would say is a stricter version of potentialism.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Miha correctly understood my question.  However, your point is well taken and I will attempt to do better.

Comment: But I don’t understand what you mean by “derive the notion of measurable cardinal.”

Comment: @MonroeEskew: Interesting.  What I mean by "deriving the notion of measurable cardinal"  is whether convergent potentialism and truth-in-the-limit-structure amounting to truth-in-the-approximating-structures would allow one to be able to define measurable cardinals as the critical point of the elementary embedding $j$: $V$ $\rightarrow$ $M$ (if at all).  Hope that helps.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: Regarding the the first-order expressibility of large cardinals, are there papers you could suggest I read regarding the notion that all large cardinals should have a first-order formulation?

Comment: Thomas, I think that what Dr. Eskew is trying to suggest is that all large cardinals in ZFC are expected to stay internal to the universe in their definition, because ZFC is a first order theory, and second-order definitions are not particularly useful when you try to stay within the bounds of first order theory.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Why doesn't the (original!) definition "$\kappa$ is measurable iff there is a $\kappa$-complete nonprincipal ultrafilter on $\kappa$" count as "local enough" for your purposes? It's completely first-order, and pays attention only to a very bounded amount of the universe (namely, whether $\kappa$ is measurable or not is determined entirely by $V_{\kappa+2}$). Indeed, these sort of "small generators" for elementary embeddings are crucial tools for understanding these more complicated (and "class-flavored") large cardinal notions ...

Comment: @NoahSchweber:   I have just read your answer and to answer the question in your above comment, it does!  Am I to presume that your method of translating supercompactness into the potentialist language  will work for large cardinal axioms of greater consistency strength than supercompactness?  Even for Rank-into-Rank axioms?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Yes. Again, bringing the term "potentialist" (etc.) into the picture just confuses things further; you're just asking whether the relevant notions are definable in ZFC (as opposed to NBG or similar). For some of these this is immediate (e.g. I1 and I3 are already formulated directly in terms of sets alone); for others it takes work. I'm not a large cardinal expert, and it's possible that there are large cardinal notions which really don't have any known ZFC formulation, but my impression is that this isn't the case.

Comment: @NoahSchweber:  Thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Paring the philosophy away (which I think just obscures things) this seems to just be a question of **definability** - the key point being that Hamkins' recursively-defined translation **works for any formula in the language of set theory**. The elementary embeddings definition of measurability *isn't* such a formula since it involves quantification over classes, and so you may ask:

> Is there a way to define measurability in ZFC alone? (And if so, how do we argue that this definition and the elementary embeddings definition actually coincide?)

- Note that this is an important question *independent of* your stance on set-theoretic (non-)reality. This is why I think it's valuable to pare away the philosophy as much as possible: there's a perfectly fine mathematical question here, and throwing philosophy into the mix just makes it harder to discern.

Such a definition **does in fact exist**, and was how measurability was defined originally. Namely, a cardinal $\kappa$ is measurable iff there is a nonprincipal $\kappa$-complete ultrafilter on $\kappa$. This is a purely combinatorial definition, and whether $\kappa$ is measurable is determined entirely by $V_{\kappa+2}$ - we don't need to "look at all of $V$."

Now, in what sense can we say that this definition equivalent to the elementary embeddings one? Well, what we do is pass to NBG, which can make perfect sense of both definitions and conservatively extends ZFC, and prove in NBG that the two definitions are equivalent.

---

Other large cardinals have similar translations. For example, supercompactness has a "class-wise" definition

> $\kappa$ is supercompact iff for every ordinal $\lambda$ there is some inner model $M$ with $M^\lambda\subseteq M$ and some elementary embedding $j_\lambda: V\rightarrow M$ with $crit(j)=\kappa$ and $j(\kappa)>\lambda$.

and a "set-wise" one

> $\kappa$ is supercompact iff for every $\mu\ge\kappa$ there is a normal measure over $[\mu]^{<\kappa}$.

Again, the latter definition just makes reference to sets, and the equivalence of the two definitions is proved in NBG (where they each make sense).

At this point it's a good idea to try to translate supercompactness into the potentialist language *without* using Hamkins' explicit translation, to get a feel for how things relate. We reason as follows:

- First, suppose $\mathcal{W}$ had a limit $V$ and $\kappa$ were supercompact in $V$. Then for every $\mu\ge\kappa\in V$ there must be a $u_\mu$ in $V$ which is a normal measure on $[\mu]^{<\kappa$}$ ...  all in the sense of $V$.
- OK, now since $V$ is the limit of $\mathcal{W}$, everything in $V$ shows up in some world in $\mathcal{W}$. Obviously this includes $\kappa$ itself - the definition of "$\kappa$ is a $\mathcal{W}$-supercompact" needs to begin with "for some $M\in\mathcal{W}$, $\kappa\in M$" - but also the $\lambda$s and $u_\lambda$s will "show up along the way."
- ... But maybe not at the same time. Whenever we have quantifier alternation we have to "move along $\mathcal{W}$" - e.g. the definition of "For all $\lambda\ge\kappa$ there is a $u_\lambda$ such that ..." needs to begin "For each world $N\supseteq M$ and each $\lambda\ge\kappa$ in $N$, there is some further world $K\supseteq N$ and some $u_\lambda\in K$ such that ..."
- Continuing in this way you wind up with a definition of "$\mathcal{W}$-supercompact" which works - that is, such that in any potentialist system $\mathcal{W}$ which has a limit $W$, "$\mathcal{W}$-supercompact" and "supercompact$^W$" are equivalent. But more than this, at this point the fully general potentialist translation Hamkins gives should be clear.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it is sufficient. Your question actually touches on a known, similar issue. A proper class is not an object in ZF, so in ZF we can't directly refer to it. Hence, again under the assumption we work in ZF, $V$ is not an object, $j$ is not an object, and if $M$ is a proper class, $M$ is also not an object. Despite all this, mathematicians working in ZF talk about these things indirectly.

The trick is, one can assume, with an exception to the case where $j \colon V \to V$, that classes $M$ and $j$ are definable from parameters by $\Sigma_2$ formulas. Moreover, the assertion that $j$ is an elementary embedding is equivalent to the assertion that for all formulas $\varphi(x)$, all ordinals $\alpha$, and all sets $a \in V_\alpha$ $$V_\alpha \models \varphi[a]$$ if and only if $j(V_\alpha) \models \varphi[j(a)]$.

So, getting back to your original question, the answer is yes. One can talk about an elementary embedding $j \colon V \to M$ without accepting the existence of $V$. The method is the same as the one outlined above.

Another way of looking at your problem is to think of a less complicated, similar scenario. In classical potentialism, one refutes the existence of $\mathbb{N}$ but accepts all its finite initial segments. Here, the problem would be whether one can talk about functions $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to A$, where $A$ is some finite set of natural numbers. In particular, let us call $n$ a *pigeonhole number* whenever there is an $m<n$ such that $f(m) = f(n)$.

The question: For every finite set of natural numbers $A$, does every function $f \colon \mathbb{N} \to A$ admit a pigeonhole number? While $f$ and $\mathbb{N}$ don't exist for a classical potentialist, he can still answer this question! He can't do it **explicitly**, but he can do it **implicitly** using larger and larger finite initial segments of $\mathbb{N}$.

Comment: What is an "object"? Why is the set of all real numbers an "object" while the class of all ordinals is not an "object"?

Comment: @Wojciech:  Welcome to MathOverflow!  How (by the way) does your answer relate to  Miha's comment (if at all)?

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin Thank you for your warm greeting :) Well, Miha points at a particular piece of $V$ where $\kappa$ reveals itself to be measurable. My answer shows a general pattern of making sense of elementary embeddings and large cardinal statements without referring to proper classes, so without referring to $V$ in particular.

Comment: @NikWeaver if you take first order ZF seriously as your foundational theory, then this follows.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: if you take NBG as your foundational theory it is wrong. This is not a serious philosophical argument.

Comment: @NikWeaver Thank you for taking an interest in my answer. I wrote that proper classes are not objects _in general_, because usually, people have ZF in mind when they talk about set-theory. But this is not the point here. It just happens that the problem of referring to $V$ without accepting its existence is not exclusive to potentialism. It is a ubiquitous issue that we know how to circumvent.

Comment: @NikWeaver To paraphrase a philosopher, to be is to fall under the scope of a quantifier. The question of what counts as an object is at base a grammatical question.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: exactly, and statements like "a proper class, generally, is not an object" quantify over classes.

Comment: @NikWeaver Now we're mixing formal and informal mathematical talk.  In ordinary language, I can noun-ify anything I want, and also perform verbatimization and make adjectivity.  English grammar is somewhat flexible, especially on the internet.  But when some says "proper classes are not objects," I take that to be talking about what counts as an object in a formal system.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: I think it's clear that the posted answer could be expressed in a formal metalanguage, and in that metalanguage by your (Quine's) criterion proper classes are objects. Now you may feel that the target system ZF is what really matters and assertions in the metasystem aren't to be taken seriously, but then you have the problem that the answer formulated here ("is equivalent to the assertion that for all formulas $\phi(x)$ ...") only makes sense in the metalanguage. So you're kind of trying to have your cake and eat it too.

Comment: @NikWeaver I disagree. Whether something is an object depends on the context or rules, which we may change if we like. Instead of having one absolute notion of object, we can explore different notions in different formal systems.  I read his assertion that “proper classes are generally not objects” as saying that in some contexts (i.e. ZF), there aren’t such things as proper classes. The post explained how talk involving definable proper classes can eliminated.

Comment: @MonroeEskew: well, I basically agree with these points.

Comment: What concerned me about the original answer was that it seemed to be making a global statement ("$V$ is not an object ... regardless of our philosophical inclinations").

Comment: As someone who takes MK seriously as a foundational theory (with a preference towards additional class collection axioms/reflection principles) I had the same reaction as Nik — a set is a class which is a member of some other class, but proper classes are objects too.

Comment: @AlecRhea It was not my intention to suggest all this. Please let me know if the edited version raises any concerns.

Comment: @ThomasBenjamin I have expanded my answer by an additional argument

Comment: @WojciechAleksanderWołoszyn:  Question:  Must $f$, for $f$: $\mathbb N$ $\rightarrow$ $A$ be necessarily recursive in order for the classical potentialist to answer the question implicitly using larger and larger finite initial segments of $\mathbb N$?